# install google eclipse plugin from command line using archive of the update site

Tags: eclipse-plugin, google-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install google eclipse plugin from command line using steps from
http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2012/10/installing-eclipse-features-via-the-command-line/

I copied google eclipse plugin archive for eclipse juno into following directory :-

```
/home/ricky/_softwares/DevelopmentSoftwares/eclipsePluginsDropinsZipsFeatures/gae/
```

Now, i am trying to install google eclipse plugin from command line using below command :-

```
./eclipse -clean -purgeHistory -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -noSplash -repository jar:file:/home/ricky/_softwares/DevelopmentSoftwares/eclipsePluginsDropinsZipsFeatures/gae/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.4.2.update.site_3.2.3.zip/ -installIUs file:/var/tmp/PPFs0awM0/updateSite/site.xml.Plugin
```

where **file:/var/tmp/PPFs0awM0/updateSite/site.xml.Plugin** is the identifier retrieved using below :-[image]

Execution of command logs following error in eclipse/configuration directory :-

```
!SESSION 2013-05-07 01:42:13.111 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.6.0_37
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -purgeHistory -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:/home/ricky/_softwares/DevelopmentSoftwares/eclipsePluginsDropinsZipsFeatures/gae/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.4.2.update.site_3.2.3.zip/ -installIUs file:/var/tmp/PPFs0awM0/updateSite/site.xml.Plugin
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean -purgeHistory -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:/home/ricky/_softwares/DevelopmentSoftwares/eclipsePluginsDropinsZipsFeatures/gae/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.4.2.update.site_3.2.3.zip/ -installIUs file:/var/tmp/PPFs0awM0/updateSite/site.xml.Plugin

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-05-07 01:42:18.755
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither raw version nor format was specified: var
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.VersionParser.parse(VersionParser.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.Version.create(Version.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.Version.parseVersion(Version.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.VersionedId.<init>(VersionedId.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.VersionedId.parse(VersionedId.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.parseIUsArgument(DirectorApplication.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.processArguments(DirectorApplication.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.run(DirectorApplication.java:1031)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.director.app.DirectorApplication.start(DirectorApplication.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Any pointers or links will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command below instead.

./eclipse -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 -installIUs com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group -noSplash

The repository argument takes URLs and the id for the Google Plugin is com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e42.feature.feature.group. Take a look at http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply... :) . Is it possible to do it offline or is  it planned in p2_director roadmap to make it possible offline ?